# Place static <div> next to <div> with bootstrap grid width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, grid

On my webpage, I have a div element on the left with a static width of 300px. Right next to it, on the right, I want to display another  element which has a dynamic, flexible width (because the browser window could be resized by the user) by using the Bootstrap grid with col-12. Imagine this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div style="width:300px;"></div>
  <div class="col-12"></div>
</div>
```

The div with class="col-12" should be right next to the left div, without space in between of them, and it should be growing/flexing always to the right of the window.

Unfortunately, it seems not to work, having a static px-width on the left element, and on the right an flex element with col-12. The second div is always BELOW the first div. Do you know a solution? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try placing the div with static width outside the container and fixing the margins?

Comment: Thank you! That sounds like a good solution. I tried now what you've written. It's not working yet, but I think it would if the margin problem gets fixed. In the static div I have a chart component by dev-extreme. I don't understand why, but right to the static div, there's actually margin, expanding to the right of the window. So the second, flexible div, is still **below** the first div. I don't know how to fix the margin because when I expect with chrome, the margin comes from an svg element. Not the div itself. Do you know what to do, or what did you mean by fixing the margins? Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try giving the second div in the row the class "col".

```
<div class="row">
  <div style="width:300px;"></div>
  <div class="col"></div>
</div>
```

Regards!

Comment: Thx a lot, it worked! I can't give you an upvote because I haven't reached 15 rep. points yet but thx anyway. Didn't expect it could be solved this way

Comment: No problem! Bootstrap really is great in my opinion!